# How do I create a list object of scraped hrefs from a webpage?

Tags: python, web-scraping, href

This code prints the list I am looking to assign to a list object:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request

webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/events/completed')

print("result code: " + str(webUrl.getcode()))

data = webUrl.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for table in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(table['href'])
```

But when I try to assign this list to an object name "links" I only get the last link.

```
for table in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    links = table['href']

print(links)
```

Comment: That is because you are overriding the values with each loop and get the last value. Try `links = [table['href'] for table in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]`

print(links)

Comment: or, initialize links as a list (`links = []`) before the loop, and then append inside the loop (`links.append(table['href'])`),